# Is there something like RecipeOperator in Airflow?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I know that there is the `PythonOperator` in Airflow, but I was wondering if there is anything like `RecipeOperator` for running recipes in a DAG. If not, how could I create one ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in RecipeOperator. However, you do have the ability to create your own operators with Airflow:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html

You could create operators your commonly used recipes and then call them as you just described.